# Sarcastic dialogue "Well, not as much as you need to"

Tags: translation, nuances

Let's suppose there is a hypothetical tense conversation where one says:

− Maybe you should try to think a little bit (or, "how about you think a little")

And the other person replies:

− Well, not as much as you need to

How's the following:

> − 少し考えてみたらどうですか
>   − 考えてみるのはお前ほどう必要がない

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice try but the last half of 「考えてみるのはお前ほどう必要がない」 makes little sense.

Native speakers might say:

> 「考{かんが}えてみた方{ほう}がいいのはお前{まえ}だろ！」 or
>
> 「お前の方こそ、考えてみるべきだ。」

This would change the meaning a little bit, but a ***very*** common reply in this kind of situation is:

> 「お前に言｛い｝われたくない（よ）！」 or
>
> 「お前にだけは言われたくない（よ）！」

I could make these more "street" and slangy if I wanted but since it's Christmas time, I will refrain from doing it.

Comment: それはこっちのセリフ is another common one I think